# OpenGL - Same dimensions on multiple devices

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want my square to fit the width of the screen.
I've managed to do this on my device as follows:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Clears the screen and depth buffer.
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    // Replace the current matrix with the identity matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, -1.6f);

    new Plane(1f,1f).draw(gl);
}
```

So my plane is 1f wide and 1f high. By moving the part into the screen 1.6f, the square neatly fits the width of the screen. But on other devices, the square becomes too large and falls partly outside the screen.

How can I fit the width of the square to the width of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just starting out on android and openGL so there may be some helper classes that I don't know of.

The problem is IMO in the aspect ratio (aspectRatio=screenWidth/screenHeight). This varies across devices, which causes the problem of the plane leaving the screen. You should scale everything based on the aspect ratio or make some window that is always across the full width of the screen but varies in the height (the height is adjusted based on the aspect ratio you wish to have).

If you use the identity projection and camera I think you stay in NDC space (or something like that) so if you render a quad in this space with the edges in the -1 or +1 you should fill the entire screen with the quad.